# C# Best way to convert dynamic to string

Tags: c#

The following gets a field from a DataTable and converts it to string.  Is there a cleaner way to convert dynamic to string?

```
dynamic value = dataTable.Rows[i].Field<dynamic>(columnName);
value = (value == null) ? null : value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
string value = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i][columnName]);
```

the standard formatting will kick in, without the need for things like generics, extension methods or dynamic.

Comment: Isn't it even easier than that? No need to convert, right?  Isn't this ok? string value = dataTable.Rows[i][columnName];

Comment: @cloud that will only work if it already *is* a string. Convert doesn't care what it is.

Comment: So should we always use convert, then, to be safe, when working with dynamics, or is it an "it depends" type situation?

Comment: @cloudsteifebro on the contrary, I'd say that usually there is no need to use dynamic, and it hurts you lots

Answer (score 22):

First of all as **Marc** mentioned in his answer "*the standard formatting will kick in, without the need for things like generics, extension methods or dynamic*" , so in your case you don't have to use `dynamic` keyword , you can just convert directly to string, but talking about converting from dynamic to string I have two ways:

**First way**

```
string x = Convert.ToString(value) // value is a dynamic object
```

> **pros:** this is a good way of conversion if you are not sure whether the compiled data type supports casting to string or it's hard coded
> as **int** for instance,
>
> **cons:** this way can cause errors if your are trying to make `Convert.ToString(value) // value is a dynamic object` inside an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) , when I do so it
> gives me this error : *"Extension methods cannot be dynamically
> dispatched. Consider **casting** the dynamic arguments or calling the
> extension method without the extension method syntax"*.

so if you are for example using Asp.Net Core `HttpContext.Session.SetString()`
and you put `Convert.ToString(value) // value is dynamic object` as an inline conversion in the arguements it will give you the error in the **cons** secion, to resolve this you can assign a variable outside the function arguments to the `Covert.ToString(value)` result then send the variable to the extension function arguements :

```
dynamic value = 10;
HttpContext.Session.SetString("key",Convert.ToString(value));  <-- error
```

resolve:

```
dynamic value = 10;
string x = Convert.ToString(value);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("key",x);  // works fine
```

or use the second way (casting), **make sure the compiled data type supports casting to string**

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("key",(string)value);
```

---

**Second Way**
[cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) `dynamic` to `string` if the compiled *data type* supports it

```
string x = (string)value;  //value is dynamic object
```

> **pros:** -it's useful if you want to make inline conversion inside an
> [Extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) arguements
> -also useful if you want to make sure that the compiled data type supports casting to *string* and generate an exception based on this

**cons:** this doesn't work on all data types so if you want a more generic conversion method the first way is recommended

---

as mentioned here in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) "The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to **bypass compile-time type checking**. Instead, these operations are **resolved at run time.**"

So the `dynamic` variable's data type is compiled at run time and takes a type other than `dynamic`, and you can use [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) if the interpreted object supports it or use `Convert.ToString()` for more generic type conversion.

PS: if you are converting to a data type other than string you may face data loss , like converting float to int , so be aware of that.

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the value of the field *is* a string, hence why OP is asking for how to *convert* it to a string. Your code will only work if the object is *actually* a string, whereas the accepted answer will work as long as `Convert.ToString` can handle it, which is heaps more likely. Note that, as an example, if the underlying value is an `int`, you'll get a runtime error of `RuntimeBinderException`: "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen actually _casting_ is a way of conversion and can work with some data types that are not dealt with in C# as a string like Newtonsoft`JObject` you can convert **numeric** data inside json string to string with _casting_, and who said he want to guarantee that the value of the field is a string , maybe he want to throw an exception if it isn't.

Comment: After updating VisualStudio yesterday I was able to do this:
`var listOfInts = new List<int>();`
`var x = listOfInts.Select(i => Convert.ToString(i));`

Comment: I have found that this explanation is very useful. Since I develop apps with Xamarin, this overload string error always comes up when the linker behaviour set to SDK Only. Maybe xamarin cannot read string out of dynamic, so putting `(string)dy_obj.var` make it works rather than `Convert.ToString(dy_obj.var)`

Answer (score 1):

I have a case where the dynamic should be a string, but in an error case is a number (code I call into and can't change is doing that).

In my case I do:

```
string x = value as string;
if (x == null)
{
   // error condition
} else {
   //use x here
}
```

Comment: Imo its better to use the `is` keyword, like `if (x is null) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain of providing a `string` from your `dynamic` variable. Right bellow, an example of `function` where I control if a value is null or not from a `dynamic`.

```
private void AddIfNotNull(List <dynamic> list, dynamic item) 
    {
       string value = item?.value?.ToString();
    
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
         list.Add(item);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Convert.ToString doesn't work for me since my data are double[][] and result will be "System.Double[][]"

```
double[,] figure_geometry = new double[2, 2] { { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 2.0, 2.0 } };
string geometry = JsonSerializer.Serialize(figure_geometry);
```

Works well

Comment: How does this answer the question? "Is there a cleaner way to convert `dynamic` to `string` from a `DataTable`?"

Comment: It answers directly. This is the cleanest way to convert because others suggested can have bad result in some cases.

Comment: The question is about converting a `dynamic` type reference to a `string` from a `DataTable` and you've introduced something called `figure.geometry` and you're using a `JsonSerializer` to turn it into something called `markerDto.geometry`? And you're said you're converting `double[][]` to `double[][]`? The only thing in common is the word "convert". Please delete this answer.

Comment: The question is "how to convert dynamic to string". There is nothing to do with DataTable. You can have any types of data and not all of them will be converted by Convert.ToString

Comment: Read the question again. It specifically mentions `DataTable` and has this code: `dataTable.Rows[i].Field<dynamic>(columnName)`. Your code converts `double[,]` to `string`. It's not the same.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I see now that `double[,]` to `string` is the same as `dynamic` to `string`. `DataTable` was a furphy.