# C# Dynamic select List of strings

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I'm trying to get `List` of strings from my dynamic object list and it keeps saying that:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`'

I'm  selecting a property and use `.ToString()` on it:

```
var objects = new List<dynamic>();
//filling objects here

List<string> things = objects.Select(x => x.nameref.ToString()).ToList();
```

So isn't it a valid List of strings? Why compiler is assuming that this list is of type `dynamic`?

I've tried also converting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827407/c-sharp-best-way-to-convert-dynamic-to-string) answer, but it keeps giving me same error.

Anyone knows how to make it `List<string>`?

EDIT:

Why isn't it working? Because you can make **mess** like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ToString()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and compiler won't know if `ToString` returns `string` or `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although Rob's answer works fine, let me suggest an alternative: Cast `nameref` to the correct type (replace `(object)` by a more specific cast, if you happen to know the type of `nameref`):

```
List<string> things = objects.Select(x => ((object)x.nameref).ToString()).ToList();
```

The advantage of that solution is that `ToString` is statically resolved. Thus, the method call is

- guaranteed to return `string`, since the compiler knows that you are calling [Object.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bxwbwt2(v=vs.110).aspx) (or an overridden variant thereof) and
- faster and cleaner. This solution keeps dynamic resolution to the absolute minimum needed (i.e., the resolution of `x.nameref`). Typos in the call to `ToString` are caught by the compiler.

(Of course, if the type of `nameref` happens to be string, you can just drop the call to `ToString()`, making your code even cleaner and shorter.)

Answer (score 20):

You need to cast the items, like so:

```
List<string> things = objects.Select(x => x.nameref.ToString()).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

The reason why it's not recognizing that `ToString()` returns a string is that it's called on a `dynamic` object, and the method binding is done at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using Cast, like so:

```
List<string> things = objects.Select(x => x.nameref).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

You could also try casting in the `Select` itself:

```
List<string> things = objects.Select(x => x.nameref as string).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, conversion to the desired `List<string>` can be done as follows.

```
var objects = new List<dynamic>();

// filling objects here

List<string> things = objects.Select(x => x.nameref.ToString()).Cast<string>.ToList();
```