# C# error while deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I am using json.net to deserialize incoming json in a WebApi service.

```
var lines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

After reading a number of other similar answers, it is still throwing this error:

```
The best overloaded method match for  'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Input json that is used in Postman for post:

```
{ "data": [
{"zipcode":"56033","line1":"610 4TH ST","city":"FROST","state":"MN","cid":"1770"},
{"zipcode":"56033","line1":"45375 30TH ST","city":"FROST","state":"MN","cid":"1771"},
{"zipcode":"56033","line1":"115 4TH ST","city":"FROST","state":"MN","cid":"1772"}
]}
```

The poco classes were created using: http://json2csharp.com .

```
  public class Datum
  {
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string line1 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string cid { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is what I see when I debug the api:

```
{{
  "data": [
    {
      "zipcode": "56032-0056",
      "line1": "208 MAIN BOX 56",
      "city": "FREEBORN",
      "state": "MN",
      "cid": "1732"
    },
    {
      "zipcode": "56033",
      "line1": "610 4TH ST",
      "city": "FROST",
      "state": "MN",
      "cid": "1770"
    },
    {
      "zipcode": "56033",
      "line1": "45375 30TH ST",
      "city": "FROST",
      "state": "MN",
      "cid": "1771"
    },
    {
      "zipcode": "56033",
      "line1": "115 4TH ST",
      "city": "FROST",
      "state": "MN",
      "cid": "1772"
    },
    {
      "zipcode": "56033",
      "line1": "E 4TH ST",
      "city": "FROST",
      "state": "MN",
      "cid": "1773"
    }
  ]
}}
```

Not sure why webapi is adding an extra set of curly braces or how to prevent them.

Anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: @GillBates Sry, April 1st habit. `json` probably is what OP wrote as "Input json"

Comment: @Sentry I got that.. what is the variable `json`, you don't show it in the code.

Comment: @Sentry oh you're not even OP, lol.

Comment: Specifically, how is the variable (or member) `json` declared?  Maybe it's not actually declared as a string.

Comment: It is the Input json described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your json variable is a string, it will work.  Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dgTfb1) demonstrating.

Comment: The json variable is coming in from the api: 
public List<dynamic> PostAddressesByLine1Batch(string key, string product, [FromBody] dynamic data)

Comment: Ok, @kman gave the suggestion about the variable being a string. The current parameter is set to dynamic or the data comes through the api as null.
So adding var json = data.ToString(); and then var lines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json); correctly deserializes.

Comment: My error was to try to process a dynamic directly to Deserialize. You need to force it to string and the error stops happening. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827407/c-sharp-best-way-to-convert-dynamic-to-string

Comment: I also was trying to deserealize a dynamic directly. Just applied a .ToString() to the dynamic variable.